# What is the best operating system for a server?

Tags: operating-system

What would you suggest would be the best operating system for a web server?

If possible, please enumerate the advantages and disadvantages if there are any...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use an operating system you have an administrator account for.

A mainstream flavour of Linux is a great choice for stability, but if no one knows how to look after it it's a bad idea. The same goes for any other platform you can name.

Answer (score 2):

If the language is PHP, then go with a Linux system. Windows also supports it, but it seems to me that Linux is what most people use for PHP, and therefore there is more documentation to set up a decent Linux server with PHP.

I have no idea what distribution of Linux to use though, but I'm sure someone does :)

Answer (score 1):

I would say [CentOS](http://www.centos.org/) - famous for its stability. I used to work as an administrator for a hosting provider - we used it and never had problems with it.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I prefer Solaris or a BSD for stability.  However, both Linux and Windows are easier to operate and offer many more standard features with only slightly less reliability.

Go with what you know best and you'll get the best results.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on the function of the webserver. What services should it provide? Should there be a homepage, and what language should that be in, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Either Linux or Windows will do the job fine. If you're doing this for yourself then Linux is an easier route because there are many free options.

If you're asking on behalf of a company who doesn't mind paying for things then it really depends on what the employees have experience in.

Comment: Just the opposite, linux might be free but requires much more technical knowledge than Windows. If you're going with a provider, then definitely linux

Comment: I wouldn't say it requires 'much' more. I mean, these days with popular distros like Ubuntu it's really no harder than Windows. Some may argue (myself included) that with package management systems some tasks are quite a bit easier than in Windows.